# Android canvas draw order

Tags: android, android-canvas, draw, android-drawable, z-axis

I want to draw a border around my circle drawable.

I have this code:

```
  public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    myDrawable.draw(canvas);
    canvas.drawArc(toHighlightBounds, 0F, 360F, /* useCenter= */ false, borderPaint);
}
```

How come the output is similar if I change the lines order?

```
  public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawArc(toHighlightBounds, 0F, 360F, /* useCenter= */ false, borderPaint);
    myDrawable.draw(canvas);
}
```

Shouldn't the order dictates the z-axis? What is drawn above the other?

Comment: Could you share screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure but I think it has something to do with the way variables work.

For example, Let's say I make a data class with a drawable in it.

I then set the drawable to an image view

```
myImageView.setImageDrawable(myClassObject.drawable)
```

Here come's the funny part, if I now change the drawable of my object to something else, it will also change in the image view.

Im not sure if this is it and if it is an easy explanation but this is  my guess